# Laravel 5.2 Auth::check() returns null in store() action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I am using JWT Authentication (Laravel 5.2) for my API project. 
`Auth::check()` is returning `false` (And also `null` for `Auth::user())` only in `store()` action in `AgentuserController`. But if I change action name to something else (trystore) then it's returning `true` and correct logged-in user for `Auth::user()`

Any idea?